# Problem with classicthesis package loaded in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, classicthesis, scrlttr2

Why the following code does not compile? How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrlttr2` is a letter class. I hope you don't mind me asking, but why do you need `classicthesis` for a letter? I guess it wasn't designed for such a class...

Comment: `classicthesis` relies upon usual sectioning commands like `\section` being defined (and on `\chapter` since you're not using `classicthesis`' `nochapters` option). They're not available in the `scrlttr2` class, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `classicthesis` package relies on the usual sectioning commands such as `\section` being defined. For example it loads [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) which it uses to define the sectioning formats.

However, the `scrlttr2` class does not define sectioning commands since they're not needed for a letter.

But then, `classicthesis` is meant for formatting a *thesis* and not a *letter*...

If you define dummy commands for the sectioning commands and the `figure` and `table` floats (that  aren't defined in `scrlttr2` either as they're not needed for a letter, too) you can avoid the immediate errors:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Musterman}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstr.\,1\\54321 Musterstadt}

\makeatletter
\def\section{}
\newcounter{section}
\def\l@section{}
\def\subsection{}
\def\l@subsection{}
\def\subsubsection{}
\def\l@subsubsection{}
\def\paragraph{}
\def\l@paragraph{}
\def\subparagraph{}
\def\l@subparagraph{}
\newcounter{figure}
\def\l@figure{}
\def\figurename{}
\newcounter{table}
\def\l@table{}
\def\tablename{}
\def\@pnumwidth{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Otto Normalverbraucher\\Normalstr.\,1\\12345 Normalstadt}
\opening{}


\closing{}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I had need! ;) A question: What are the horizontal little lines at the left of the letter body?

Comment: @FormlessCloud Folding guides? (To help fold the letter correctly for insertion into an envelope.)

Comment: They are fold marks. There is an option to turn them off but I can't remember it at the moment. You should be able to find it in [KOMA-Script's documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/scrguien.pdf)

Comment: @PaulStanley Thank you all guys you're fantastic. For your knowledge the option is "foldmarks=false"